# Create a user with django-social-auth parameter passing access_token

Tags: django, facebook, api, django-socialauth

How to create a user with [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/) parameter passing access_token?
Example:
django-social-auth.create_user(access_token= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...')
Is this possible?

I do this because I get an API in access_token from it must create the user in the database system.
www.mysite/api/new/user/[token]/

Backend: facebook

Comment: Well, just query the Graph API for `/me?access_token=…`, and you’ll get the basic user data (assuming you’re having a _user_ access token).

Comment: No, it's not possible. django-social-auth keeps things like the access_token on separate model from the built-in User model.